# how to create quad area from sprite (texture2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, texture2d

I have an image and add it to unity as readble/writable sprite. It is 32x32. But I dont know how to give coordinates to vertices vector so that it gives me a quad area that have the same shape as my sprite. For exmaple if I have a Heart.png 32x32 pixel sprite, then I want a heart shaped area from quads

```
void Awake()
    {
        texture2D = sprite.texture;
        mesh = new Mesh();
        mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        

        for(int i=0; i< texture2D.width; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j< texture2D.height; j++)
            {

                Color color = texture2D.GetPixel(i, j);
                if(color.a == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(), new Vector3(), new Vector3(), new Vector3() };
                indeces = new int[]{ 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3 };
                mesh.vertices = vertices;
                mesh.triangles = indeces;

            }
        }

        mf.sharedMesh = mesh;
    }
```

Comment: I am so new at unity and trying to learn it :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is a bit tricky.

What I would do (because it is easier to implement - not because it is more efficient!) is basically for each pixel create a small Quad (4 vertices -> 2 triangles) with the according color.

```c#
[SerializeField] private Texture2D texture;
[SerializeField] private Mesh mesh;
[SerializeField] private MeshFilter mf;

[ContextMenu("TEST")]
private void Awake()
{
    // Just in case use the mesh format that allows more vertices
    
    if(!mf) mf = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
    
    mesh = new Mesh {indexFormat = IndexFormat.UInt32};

    // Create these ONCE and fill them bit by bit
    var verticesList = new List<Vector3>();
    var trianglesList = new List<int>();
    var colors = new List<Color>();

    // Do this in ONE call -> more efficient
    var pixels = texture.GetPixels();

    // Place the pivot in the center of the texture
    var pivotOffset = -new Vector3(texture.width / 2f, texture.height / 2f);

    for (var i = 0; i < texture.width; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j < texture.height; j++)
        {
            var color = pixels[i + j * texture.width];

            if (color.a == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // Add the pixel color for the FOUR vertices we create
            colors.Add(color);
            colors.Add(color);
            colors.Add(color);
            colors.Add(color);

            // Create the four vertices around this pixel position
            var vertex0 = pivotOffset + new Vector3(i - 0.5f, j - 0.5f, 0);
            var vertex1 = pivotOffset + new Vector3(i + 0.5f, j - 0.5f, 0);
            var vertex2 = pivotOffset + new Vector3(i - 0.5f, j + 0.5f, 0);
            var vertex3 = pivotOffset + new Vector3(i + 0.5f, j + 0.5f, 0);

            // Store the current length of so far vertices => first new vertex index
            var currentIndex = verticesList.Count;

            // Add the vertices to the list
            verticesList.Add(vertex0);
            verticesList.Add(vertex1);
            verticesList.Add(vertex2);
            verticesList.Add(vertex3);

            // Two triangles for front side
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 2);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 3);

            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 3);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 1);
            
            // For double sided add the inverted faces for the back as well
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 3);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 2);

            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 1);
            trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 3);
        }
    }

    // Finally apply them ONCE to the mesh
    mesh.vertices = verticesList.ToArray();
    mesh.triangles = trianglesList.ToArray();
    mesh.colors = colors.ToArray();

    mf.sharedMesh = mesh;
}
```

Looks like

[image]

as you can see you can than play with the materials. By storing the pixel colors into the mesh colors you can simply use a shader that supports vertex colors.

---

Further explanations:

1. The `GetPixels` returns a flat single dimensional array. Within that array the pixels of the texture are layed out horizontally line by line.

   That means that lets say you have a grid like

   ```
    7 8 9 |
    4 5 6 |-height=3
    1 2 3 |
    _____
      |
    width=3
   ```

   it becomes

   ```
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
   ```

   (Unity texture coordinate start 0-based at the lower-left corner)

   So in order to access a certain entry e.g. the `6` which is at pixel coordinate `x=2, y=1` you have to go

   ```
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
                  |
    x(=2) + y(=1) * width(=3)
   ```
2. As said my simple solution would be to not create a single vertex per pixel as you tried but rather create a square. For that we need for vertices like

   ```
    p-0.5x+0.5y        p+0.5x+0.5y
    V------------------V
    |                  |
    |                  |
    |        p         |
    | (actualPosition) |
    |                  |
    V------------------V
    p-0.5x-0.5y        p+0.5x-0.5y
   ```

   I hope that awesome ascii art makes it somehow clear :D
3. Finally the [`triangles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-triangles.html) of a mesh in Unity is simply an `int[]` where every element refers to one vertex index in the [`vertices`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-vertices.html) array and where always `3` consecutive indices form one triangle.

   Within one triangle the winding order of the vertices defines in which direction it faces.

   - The normal faces towards you if the vertices are in clockwise order.
   - The normal faces away from you if the vertices are in counter-clockwise order.

   See e.g. [Unity Manual - Creating a Quad](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Example-CreatingaBillboardPlane.html) and I hope these graphics explains the rest

   [image]
   [image]

   In my example for each pixel I add a quad of four vertices in the order

   ```
    2----3
    |  / |
    | /  |
    0----1
   ```

   then I add the two triangles clockwise

   - `0` `2` `3`
   - `0` `3` `1`

   and counter clockwise (to have them double sided)

   - `0` `3` `2`
   - `0` `1` `3`

   And finally since we don't want the index starting at 0 but rather at the `currentIndex` the same values before become

   - `currentIndex+0` `currentIndex+2` `currentIndex+3`
   - `currentIndex+0` `currentIndex+3` `currentIndex+1`

   and

   - `currentIndex+0` `currentIndex+3` `currentIndex+2`
   - `currentIndex+0` `currentIndex+1` `currentIndex+3`

Comment: sorry my low level questions but **1.** whats the point of adding i to j* texture.width -> `var color = pixels[i + j * texture.width];`  **2.**   incoordinate of vertex Vectors, you are adding/substracting 0.5f, what does it mean, I mean why do we move vector to left or right etc. **3.** `trianglesList.Add(currentIndex + 2);` we are adding 2, 3 or 1 ? I really dont understand the math logic of those things like why did we need to move coordinates? Again sorry my questions:(

Comment: @anónimo I added explanations at the bottom of the answer ;)

Comment: you are so perfect to be human:) thank you for your time